# What does "poll" in django mean?

Tags: django

In Django doc it is said

Creation of a basic **poll** application will consist of two parts:

A public site that lets people view **polls** and vote in them.
An admin site that lets you add, change, and delete **polls**.

I couldn't find any clear description of a poll. So what does it mean?

Comment: poll is a name they give to the doc example application. As you can see, there are definitions for questions and answers in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't be confused with the word poll. Poll here is used only in reference with vote, and nothing related to django as such. What it means to say is to have a site for voting, on which people can view previous votes (polls) and can cast their own vote. And an admin site to change and delete these votes casted by the people.

It is like many sites on which you may like some post or article, and can also see the current likes for that post. And site admin has a right to delete or change your votes.